# MDTextField is hide under Keyboard Android

Tags: kivy, kivymd

I have a form with some MDTextFields and the one that is in the last position below, when I open the keyboard to type, it is hidden below it, how can I do when I open the keyboard the MDTextField object moves and remains visible to see what is being written.

look images

[Normal Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSEdS.jpg)

[Form with keyboard open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uOlI.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

COPY/PASTE THE CODE IN YOUR main.py FILE:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.keyboard_anim_args = {'d': .2, 't': 'in_out_expo'}
Window.softinput_mode = "below_target"
```

Comment: Thanks @AmalMathew now is ok the form... thank!